# Chainstay Protector, Will it interfere with rear derailleur gear cable?

Tags: mountain-bike, derailleur-rear, frame-protection

I have a chainstay protector wrapped all around the chainstay.

Will this affect the rear-derailleur gear cable which on my bike is externally routed?

Comment: How thick is this chainstay protector? Usually the cables have 1 or 2mm distance to the frame. So a thin protector or velcro strap might just fit under them. You can also make a perfectly fine chainstay protector out of a piece of old road bike tyre or inner tube and some cable ties.

Comment: Some protectors are stick-on and cover the upper half of the stay only. It's quite sufficient as the chain is most likely to strike there.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your shifter cable will be separated from the chainstay by at least the thickness of the cable-housing wall, plus the thickness of the cable-stop wall. Unless you've got an unusually thick chainstay protector, it will be thinner than that. But you can eyeball it and see if it is interfering.

I use helicopter tape, which is less than 1 mm thick.