# Bicycle Chainstay Protector

Tags: frame-protection

I was going to purchase a strap on chainstay protector for my mtb, I was going to do the inner tube hack however there is an external cable which I don't want to damage/inhibit movement. Do the velcro chainstay protectors pick up loads of mud as I don't want this as it will be yet another thing to clean? Or does anyone have another ideas?

Comment: Looks like you already asked this at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/82065/chainstay-protector-will-it-interfere-with-rear-derailleur-gear-cable  ?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you split your old innertube to be one layer thick, there should be plenty of space between the exposed inner cable and the chainstay for overlaps.

If you don't split the tube, then you have 4 thicknesses of tube at the overlaps, which is a lot.